# Permissions on phpmyadmin

Tags: centos, centos5

I installed the phpmyadmin folder in the /var/www/html/ directory and I recently chmod 'd everything in the html directory to 777.

At first I realized that phpmyadmin won't run if you allow outside write access so I changed the permissions on that directory to 744.

I haven't found any good troubleshooting documentation on this problem but all I see in the error log is:

> Permissions denied : access to /phpmyadmin/index.html.var denied

I made sure the owner is the same as the rest of the files in the html folder.

The rest of the site seems to work fine and it appears I can write to the database but I cannot access phpmyadmin.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

AH! Setting permissions to 755 on the entire /html directory fixed the problem. Found the answer in this forum: [Yet another apache index html 403 problem](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/yet-another-apache-index-html-403-problem-736245/)